# How to change the size of MessageBox in c#?

Tags: c#, messagebox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# formatting a MessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421084/c-sharp-formatting-a-messagebox)

how to change the size of windows default MessageBox in c# . Is there any code for it ? i dont want to make my personalised dialog box ? so is there any solution to change the windows default messagebox size?

Comment: Write less or more text in title/message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5421126/763026

Comment: For my own standard windows forms applications I have just written a replacement for MessageBox that is resizable. You can download it here and use it like a standard MessageBox:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601900/FlexibleMessageBox-A-flexible-replacement-for-the

Regards, Jörg

Comment: what is the default size of a message and a text box ?? any one knw it ?

Comment: It seems to break lines at some point. From a quick screenshot test it seems the message box width is 480 pixels at that point.

Comment: Adding more text does not change width.  Long text in the title is simply cut short and appended with `...`, while long text in the message is wrapped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create custom form and set properties as you want

Answer (score 2):

There is no code for this because it is not possible. For creating your own message box you can check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9656/Dissecting-the-MessageBox) for instance.

Comment: Holy cow that's a bunch of code for something that can be done using a custom form (designed in seconds) and a call to `ShowDialog()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try and make a custom class, that holds your design/properties.

You could make a function in your custom message box class, that will call your "Bigger messagebox" and set the text

`CustomBox.Show("sdhsfs")`

[This](http://tutplusplus.blogspot.com/2010/07/c-tutorial-create-your-own-custom.html) may help with the class (You will have to add a size Tag to the constructor)

Also, the tutorial uses static methods, make an instance instead. This will allow multiple message boxes, all with different text.